# Grid do Primeng não funciona

Tags: angular, primeng

Estou usando diversos componentes do primeng normalmente como botões, inputs, menu, etc. Todos funcionando normalmente no meu projeto em angular 10. Menos o grid simplesmente não está organizando nada na tela, por exemplo:

```
<div clas="ui-g">
<div clas="ui-g-8">
<h1>1<\h1>
<\div>
<div clas="ui-g-2">
<h1>2<\h1>
<\div>
<div clas="ui-g-2">
<h1>3<\h1>
<\div>
<\div>
```

Era para estar distribuído na tela da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o grid é a única coisa que não funciona, não sei se ficou muito claro. Mas se alguém já passou por isso, peço ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Grid Está Obsoleto no Primeng Angular ao inves disso use FlexGrid

 Instale FlexGrid

```
npm install primeflex --save
```

Adicione o no seu "styles" do arquivo angular.json

```
"node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
```

e no seu app.component.html o flexGrid ficara assim

```
    <h3>FlexGrid</h3>
    <div class="p-grid">
        <div class="p-col-8">
            <div class="box">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col-2">
            <div class="box">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col-2">
            <div class="box">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigada.